# How to display an HTML email in a web application?

Tags: javascript, html, email, mime

I wrote a web application that fetches email via IMAP. I now need to *display* these emails to the user.
I thought it would be simple (I am displaying HTML within an HTML-capable browser) until I looked into this a little... and discovered that there are *tons* of issues, such as:

- Javascript & security
- Style breaking
- Surely more

Is there a *good*, *safe* way to display an HTML email? I would err for "safe" rather than "gorgeous", even though I don't want to display just the text version of an email (which is not even guaranteed to be there anyway...)

I realise the most obvious answer is "put everything in a frame" -- is that really it though? Will it *actually* work?

I am using Node server side if it helps...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> ..most obvious answer is "put everything in a frame"...will it *actually* work?

Yes, e.g. [Whiteout Networks GmbH's WHITEOUT.IO](https://whiteout.io/) does it in [/src/tpl/read.html](https://github.com/whiteout-io/mail-html5/blob/v0.19.2/src/tpl/read.html#L66-L72) and [/src/js/controller/read-sandbox.js](https://github.com/whiteout-io/mail-html5/blob/v0.19.2/src/js/controller/read-sandbox.js#L4). Some of the security issues are handled by [DOMPurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify)

> ..there are tons of issues..Is there a *good*, *safe* way..?

I know the message data format also under names [EML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email#Filename_extensions) or [MHTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML) so looking for a *good* "XY to HTML converter" or "HTML5 document viewer with XY support" may point you to a usable results (e.g. [GroupDocs.Viewer](http://groupdocs.com/html5-document-viewer))

Some e-mail clients (e.g. GMail) don't use `iframe`, instead they use a mail parser (e.g. [andris9/mailparser](https://github.com/andris9/mailparser)) and a HTML parser (e.g. [cheeriojs/cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio)) to extract an e-mail-safe-html subset (see [Stack Overflow: What guidelines for HTML email design are there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127498/what-guidelines-for-html-email-design-are-there) and [Stack Overflow: Styling html email for GMail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056172/styling-html-email-for-gmail) for some examples) or use a [HTML sanitizer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_sanitization) (e.g. [Google's Caja](https://developers.google.com/caja/), [cure53/DOMPurify](https://github.com/cure53/DOMPurify)) and embed the code directly into the page.

But it is not always an easy thing, there is no consensus on what constitutes the e-mail-safe-html subset and you certainly don't wont to inline possibly infected attachments nor run anonymous [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) scripts within the [secured](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Secure) user's session.

Anyway, as always, studying source code of various e-mail clients (see [Wikipedia: Comparison of email clients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_email_clients)) is the way to find out..

Comment: Will accept the answer as long as it mentions Google's Caja https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/wiki/JsHtmlSanitizer which was the key to the solution of my problem

Comment: @Merc in that case you can accept your own http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer and upvote mine if it brings something useful

Comment: your answer is amazing and I think it should be the accepted one! Please just add a quick reference to caja, that's all!

Comment: @Merce done. Still, if you already know what is the answer and what actually works for you in your application then publishing a practical self-answer might be useful for future readers

Comment: The Google Caja Compiler project has now moved to here: https://developers.google.com/caja/