# gmail wont apply css when printing email from php mailer

Tags: html, css, printing, gmail

I'm trying to make a `phpmailer` that when printed applies a style, mostly font size, to get all of it to fit on a standard piece of printer paper. But when in `gmail` and selecting print I can't get the style to be applied.

```
 $mail->Body="
 <?php
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
<title>test email</title>
<style>
h1 {
color: maroon;
font-size: 10px;
}
@media print { 
h1 {
color: maroon;
font-size: 10px;
}
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>html EMAIL IS COMING SARA</h1>
</body>
</html> 
";
```

I have tried it this way but the email wont send at all. I recieve the following:

`PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'color' (T_STRING)`

```
$mail->Body="
<?php
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test email</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 style="color:blue;">html EMAIL IS COMING SARA</h1> 
</body>
</html> 
 ";
```

Comment: you will find your answer here >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056172/styling-html-email-for-gmail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of php string quotes **"**

Use the following code:

```
$mail->Body="

 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>test email</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 style='color:blue;'>html EMAIL IS COMING SARA</h1> 
</body>
</html> 
 ";
```