# EMail Content - HTML+ CSS email content does not look proper in gmail

Tags: php, gmail, html-email

I have created HTML + CSS mail content.

When I open this email in mail clients like Thunder Bird, it works perfectly. 
When I open same message in gmail, it breaks and does not take inline CSS that I have provided in < style > tag.

Attaching screenshot for the same.[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Styling HTML email for Gmail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9056172/styling-html-email-for-gmail)

Comment: you write in-line css fine .

Answer (score 0):

Gmail ignores style sheets (external and internal) so you will need to inline your styles to make them work. ref: https://litmus.com/blog/understanding-gmail-and-css-part-1

good inliners:

- http://foundation.zurb.com/emails/inliner.html
- http://templates.mailchimp.com/resources/inline-css/

Reference of CSS that works in different HTML email clients:

http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/