# Import component works when in app folder but not when installed as node_module via npm

Tags: angular, typescript

I've got an angular 2 component that when I put in `app-name/src/app/component-folder/component.ts` and import like `import {Component} from './component-folder/component'` works just fine.

But when the component is installed to the `app-name/node_modules` folder at `app-name/node_modules/component-folder/component` and I do

`import {Component} from 'component-folder/component'`

or `import {Component} from '../../node_modules/component-folder/component'`

It gives me this error: `Unexpected value 'Component' declared by the module 'AppModule'`

Why is that and how do I fix it?

Comment: What is "it"? tsc or angular2 runtime? Also, please add systemjs.config.js file.

Comment: I had the reverse issue (using pure js not ts)! I couldn't get an npm module to load properly, but inspired by your post here I tried copying the module local to the same directory as the file I was importing it into and it worked! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39759764/unexpected-value-fileuploadmodule-imported-by-the-module-uploadermodule-ng

Answer (score 0):

Because module resolution by tsc is different when it looks for something from `node_modules`. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html

Comment: I still don't understand how I would make it so I can import my component from the node modules. I've read a couple things about changing the `module: "commonjs"` in tsconfig, and then use `module: module.id` in the `@Component` declaration. But nothing is working yet.