# How do I prevent the Gmail app from parsing addresses and injecting links into the body of my email?

Tags: css, email, mobile, gmail, html-email

I'm currently working on an email with a lot of phyisical addresses on it, and we lay everything out using nested tables.

The addresses are typically divided across two table cells (one with the street address, and then one with the city + state)

For some reason, gmail is turning random text near the address into links, or sometimes injecting a table cell with an empty link, messing up the email's layout.

Does anyone know how I can prevent g-mail from injecting these links into our email?

Comment: Check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48784150/email-signature

Comment: @Syfer nice answer! Up-voted your answer in that other thread as that is very comprehensive.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Email signature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48784150/email-signature)

Comment: Thank you. Remove this question maybe when you can as it will be flagged as duplicate.

Comment: We're actually having a different issue because gmail is explicitly injecting a `<td>` with an `<a href` inside it. So the styling issues proposed there don't solve the problem

Comment: And the answers there are outdated, the `&zwnj;` fix does not work for us.

Comment: You question was how to disable links which is in the other link. `&zwnj;` still works and I just used one yesterday. Gmail according to my knowledge hasnt started to inject `td`'s so I am not sure whats happening in your case. It would be good if you can add code for the part that turns into a link. Once which is your code and the other after Gmail makes it a link (desktop and app will work with the same code)

Answer (score 0):

I actually had this same issue yesterday. I resolved it using this work-around for email clients meddling in triggered links.

Insert the below into the `<style>` block in your email `<head>`

```
*.x-apple-data-detectors,  /* iOS */
*.x-gmail-data-detectors,    /* Gmail */
.x-gmail-data-detectors *,
.aBn {
    border-bottom:0 !important;
    cursor:default !important;
    color:inherit !important;
    text-decoration:none !important;
    font-size:inherit !important;
    font-family:inherit !important;
    font-weight:inherit !important;
    line-height:inherit !important;
}

/* Overrides injected client link classes */
.blue-links a {
    color:#e6eaf6 !important;
    text-decoration:none !important;
}
```

Just add the `blue-links` class to the parent tag where the link is being inserted and change the `color` to what you require.

Gmail and iOS both insert unwanted `<a>` links when they encounter an address or a number that looks like it may be a phone number.

Hope this works for you as it did for me.